# How to hide my CSS and JS code so it doesn't get copied?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I intend to create an e-commerce, but I didn't want my CSS code to be visible to users, thus avoiding layout cloning. How to hide my CSS and JS code?

When I try to access the CSS code of professional sites like Spotify, I only see very strange coding and I can't see the CSS. What do they do to achieve this result?

Comment: You might want to have a google of the term "obfuscation".

Comment: Kindly check https://obfuscator.io/

Comment: just create botnet and hide it .Whoever steals your code Will pay the price

Answer (score 0):

Did you research a bit on Google on how to do this? You can make it difficult for others to copy your code via 'obfuscation'.

The sites that you've mentioned use the very same technique which makes it hard for you to comprehend the code. Although obfuscation makes it harder for someone to reverse engineer your code but for a determined attacker, it may be possible to de-obfuscate your code as well.

You may want to check out this link - https://www.bibekoli.com/tools/html-obfuscator.html as an example of a tool to help you obfuscate your code.

Comment: I only searched in Portuguese and maybe thats why I coul not find ANYTHING about it. Thanks for helping me.